Matches differs in re.search(and re.findall())
In Python 3.x code
import re
link = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Tamlah.html'
print(re.search('by_(.*).h', link).group())
print(re.findall('by_(.*).h', link))

I'm trying to find a name in the link.
Result of work.
by_Tamlah.h
['Tamlah']

Regex the same, functions different. The question is why re.search() function doesn't understand string extraction start, end regular expression ()? The correct result is Tamlah.

According to the documentation for Match.group():

...
Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned).
...

So re.search("by_(.*).h", link).group() returns the whole match, including by_ and .h.
If you specify the group, e.g.:
print(re.search("by_(.*).h", link).group(1))

Then only first capturing group is printed:
Tamlah


yes, re.search() and re.findall() are different and the fact that you got the whole match on this (re.search("by_(.).h", link).group()) is because of the group() function there which will return the entire match and for this (print(re.search("by_(.).h", link).group(1)))that prints just one is because you are more or less ranging it to just the first one match.
so if you are finding just one name strictly i'ld say you go for this (print(re.search("by_(.).h", link).group(1))) else this print(re.search("by_(.).h", link).group())
